# Soql query for retrieving images from notes and attachments

Tags: soql, query

I want retrieve image from documents in not other notes like pdf,ext... please how to write soql query

Comment: Would you mind putting some more effort into your question ? Please explain us what you are trying to do, if there is a part that you already have and what parts you do not understand. That, and tagging the questions with the best related subjects will make it easier to answer this question.  This entire site deals with salesforce, so the salesforce-crm tag should be avoided.   You can edit your question to update it.

Comment: SELECT  (SELECT Id FROM Attachments)FROM Property__c WHERE Property_Status__c = 'Active' ];

Comment: That is my code but in that i need only images

Comment: Can you try to edit that code into your question ? tip: you can format it with the {} icon.  Do you know how to identify 'images' from other attachments, is there a set of filetypes or extentions that you consider to be an image ?

Answer (score 12):

As Sdry suggested in the comments please put some effort in before asking your questions

Assuming you want to retrieve related attachment for a records,what you have to do write a query on Attachment object...

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_attachment.htm

see the example query below:

SELECT Id,Name FROM Attachments where ParentId ='id of the record for  you want to       query related attachments for' AND ContentType ='type of the attachment you want to retrive'

i have written sample code for you check below

Vf page:

```
 <apex:page Controller="Attachments">

<apex:pageBlock >
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!LA}" var="a">
<apex:column value="{!a.id}"/>
<apex:column value="{!a.name}"/>
<apex:column value="{!a.contenttype}"/>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public class Attachments {


public List<Attachment> LA{get{
                                 return [SELECT Id,Name,ContentType FROM Attachment                     where ParentId ='0019000000CHVUl'];

                                }
                            set;}

}
```

results:
[image: resulting table]

When i change the query in controller adding a filter with content type as below

```
return [SELECT Id,Name,ContentType FROM Attachment where ParentId ='0019000000CHVUl' AND contenttype in ('image/png','image/gif')];
```

Results table changes to..

[image]

Comment: Hey :D this is gonna sound harsh, but the same applies  for answers :P. Mind explaining in your answer itself how such an query works, and how images can be identified ?

Comment: `AND WHERE ContentType IN ('image/bmp', 'image/gif', 'image/jpeg', ...)` should do the trick... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type#Type_image seems like a good start

Comment: No it will shows an error like unexpected token bmp,gif....

Comment: You are confused, i have custom object(pro) in that users will update different types of notes and attachments and i want to separate images and notes(pdf,excel...)and need to display all images in vf page

Comment: i dont have any fields in that we will get only ID of image or title

Comment: i have given link in the answer please go through that page for all details on the attachment object

Answer (score 1):

You need to collect extensions you want to filter and add filtered pictures in to Collection.

```java
    List<String> imageExtensions = 
        new List<String>{'bmp', 'gif', 'jpeg', 'jpg', 'png',
                         'svg+xml', 'tiff', 'vnd.adobe.photoshop',
                         'vnd.dwg', 'x-photoshop'};
    List<ContentDocumentLink> files = new List<ContentDocumentLink>();
    files = [SELECT Id, ContentDocumentId, ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersionId,
             ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersion.Title
             FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId =: recordId 
             AND ContentDocument.FileType IN: imageExtensions];
```

This is how I do for Related Files.
List`s type is String