# retriving notes and attachments from custom object to display in vf page

Tags: apex, visualforce

How to retrieve notes and attachments from custom object through vf page.please help me and give me some example code

Comment: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/22978/soql-query-for-retrieving-images-from-notes-and-attachments this was your previous question i have added a clear description on this question now check that out please don't ask questions again and again

Comment: i want retrieve multiple images through controller based on condition is it possible

Comment: Have you looked at my answer to your previous question now,the code actually retrieves multiple images and displays them in VF page...