# How to get Attachment attached to an article using SOQL

Tags: soql, knowledge

[image]

In the screenshot attached to this Question you can find one "pdf" enclosed inside a blackbox,I need to get this using SOQL.

I am neither able to get the Object storing this attachment nor the relationship name with knowledgeArticle object.

When I click on the attachment it takes me to the following URL

https://svaruas-dev-ed--c.ap2.content.force.com/servlet/fileField?id=0BE280000008UA6

0BE is a prefix for filefielddata however not able to Use this to deduce anything.

So could anybody help me in getting the Right SOQL for this

Comment: Check This,
[SOQL Query for Attachments](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/22978/soql-query-for-retrieving-images-from-notes-and-attachments)

Comment: @naveen dhanaraj I looked into the attachment object however these are not getting stored there.Also the Id of the records in Attachment have a prefix 00P unlike 0BE in this case.thank u for looking into this

Comment: did you look at the junction between the article - ContentDocumentLink - ContentDocument ?

Answer (score 1):

You can acquire the Base64 data of the attachment, along with its FileName.

Here is the query on the Article version I used:
**SELECT Id, KnowledgeArticleId,testing_Attachment__Name__s FROM Article__kav WHERE Id='Your Article Id' AND PublishStatus='online'**

Now you can acquire the Attachment Body's base64 value on the article as per the instruction below:

1. String contentURL = "YOUR SALESFORCE INSTANCE URL VALUE"/servlet/fileField?entityId=ArticleVersionId(From above query)&field=testing_Attachment__Body__s.
2. PageReference pf = new PageReference(contentURL);
   pf.getContent();//this statement return the Blob value for the attachment/file body.

Do mention if this solves your problem.

-Jagjit